# How to de-bootstrap an angular js application in unit tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In my jasmine tests I test the app initialization the following way:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
describe('app', function () {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
    });
    it('should load without errors', function() {
        expect(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(angular.element('body'), ['app']);
        }).not.toThrow();
    });
});
}());
```

My problem is that when I run Karma i often get:

```
Expected function not to throw an exception , but it threw [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '<body>'
```

I think the best solution would be to "un-bootstrap" the application in an afterEach but I could not find any way to do so in the docs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the wrong approach, since you can't "un-bootstrap" angular. Instead don't bootstrap it in the first place, when it's not needed: Remove the "ng-app" directive from your marup where your jasmine tests are running.

Comment: I manually bootstrap the angular application outside of my tests and want to test that including the routing setup etc. Also i want my code coverage to go up :)

Comment: You shouldn't bootstrap it on your own then, when it doesn't make sense. :-)